# how to delete a line with ES characters in a certain position notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, lines

```
62020180327 00000000000344753973KOLESTON PERF.CAST.MD RAME 4/4PZ2222302620ECU0000073800000099800000000000000000000000000000000  0000 22 2200  KOLESTON
62020180327 00000000000353753976KOLESTON PERF.CAST.CH.DOR. 5/3PZ2222302620ECU0000073800000099800000000000000000000000000000000  0000 22 2200  KOLESTON
62020180327 00000000000357189272KOLESTON PERFECT 5/7          PZ2222302620ECU0000066900000089500000000000000000000000000000000  0000 22 2200ESKOLESTON
62020180327 00000000000373189267KOLESTON PERFECT 7/3          PZ2222302620ECU0000066900000089500000000000000000000000000000000  0000 22 2200ESKOLESTON
```

hi, I've a list like this one. How could i delete/remove the lines containing the characters ES at postion 141?
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general approach:

Replace this: `^.{140}ES.*(\r?\n|$)` with empty string.

Explanation:

- `^.{140}` matches the first 140 characters from the start of the line
- `ES` is the exact match you need
- `.*(\r?\n|$)` matches everything else, including the line break too.

So when you replace everything, including the line break too, then the line disappears. I.e. it doesn't even leave a blank line behind.